# Why Project Manager for Java VS Code extension is only showing me debug button rather that run?

Tags: java, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create project example with VS Code using Project Manager for Java (as part of the Extension Pack for Java, by Microsoft). On [this short tutorial](https://youtu.be/rSEGXCPZqLw?t=247) there is a run button, but for me I only see debug button:

[image]

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed the shortcut button from run to debug several months ago. So the tutorial is out-of-date: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/pull/1108

But if you really want to run your application instead of debug. You can still right-click on your project and find the run action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I understood the origin correctly it never actually was a run button, but always a debug button and you switched the icon to be more descriptive. Good call. However to me it seems confusing that the debug woud take priority in the first place. In my personal opinion I would love both side by side and I would use them too. I think I am going to submit feature request for this. You already answered my question, but I would still ask: what would be the best place to submit such request? I see both: "vscode-java-debug" and "vscode-java-dependency" repos as good candidates.

Comment: It was a real run button ago. But we received some feedbacks that they want to make the debug action as the default shortcut. Then the change happens. Put both two buttons were also considered but finally we decide to limit the number of buttons to make the view looks simply. Feel free to submit your request to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues. We'll think if there is better way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I open a Java/Maven project in my VSCode(updated to the latest 1.74.3), it also show a *add* and *debug* in the **Java Projects** view.

But it is easy to run the main application directly in VSCode.

1. Open the application class which includes a static `main` method, there is a *run/debug* icon in the top right location of the title bar. Click it to run your application directly or select *run* or *debug* from the dropdown menu.
2. Create a custom `launch.json` file. Click the *Debug* icon in the left pane to show **Run/Debug** view, and if there is no launch.json existed, it will guide to create one. In the `launch.json` file, setup a *Launch Main* task.

   ```json
   {

       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Main",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.example.demo.Main",
            "projectName": "demo"
            }
        ]
    }
   ```

   Then in the title bar of **Run/Debug** view, there is a dropdown box which includes a **Launch Main** task, click it and run your application.